# Is there a way to specify Max height and width for an image in Acumatica aspx page?

Tags: acumatica

I would like to have an image either a height of 150px and width of 200px,
when i have images with a height of over 150px  and thinner/over 200px they get stretched out to fit.
What is the best way to do this?

i have tried some alternatives by writing some code page load but it doesn't work.

I expect the output of image should be fits based on the image file is uploaded.

**Additional input need**

Hello,
The given answer is just worked for the new screens but not or the Acumatica default screen..

I have added a new image at header on stock Item screen and now when i try to add  style property using max keyword then while clicking on generate script through customization package it is getting wiping off and getting output like below any suggestions please

**Input**

`<px:PXImageView runat="server" Style='max-height:150px;max-width:200px'  DataField="UsrKWJMThumbnailURL" ID="edUsrKWJMThumbnailURL" />`

**After clicking on Generate Customization Script by editing aspx page the output is like below**

`<px:PXImageView runat="server" Width="" Height="" DataField="UsrKWJMThumbnailURL" ID="edUsrKWJMThumbnailURL" Style='width:;height:;' />`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer depends on where and how the image control is implemented. In ASPX is just not enough information to determine exact scenario.

Assuming the image was added in a form header using PXImageView control you can set the max-width and max-height in CSS style property of the control.

```
<px:PXImageView runat="server" DataField="UsrImage" ID="edImg" Style='max-height:60px' />
```

[image]